# In mysql How can I multiply two tables?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Basically what I want is cross product of two tables.

```
t1 is :
    +------------+
    | student    |
    +------------+
    | 1234567890 | 
    | 1234567890 | 
    | 1234567890 | 
    | 000000001  | 
    +------------+
t2 is:
    +--------+
    | number |
    +--------+
    |      1 | 
    |      3 | 
    +--------+
```

How can I get a table which has two columns and 8 entries which are crosss product of values in t1 and t2 ?

Comment: What would the resulting product table contain?

Comment: Example of expected output please

Comment: Good JOIN info: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000976.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select student, number, from t1, t2;

Comment: Or: `Select student, number from t1 join t2 on 1;`

Answer (score 7):

I think you need a CROSS JOIN.

It'll join both tables on all rows.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 CROSS JOIN t2
```